# WPF Toolkit Datagrid Sorting

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid, ironruby

Our client has wants to sort the values in a WPF datagrid.

One of the columns is a time span column. However, it's in string format. Here are sample data.

-1 Week - Reorganize Staff

-2 Month - Design Website

-5 Years - Negotiate Merger

I've managed to turn the string data into a numeric value corresponding to the dates. I've also put that column in the datagrid. Now the client wants to sort the column with the string span. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add property to the class

```
public string StringSpan { get; set; }
public TimeSpan Span { get { return ParseSomehow(StringSpan); } }
```

and use `SortMemberPath="Span"` for your `DataGridColumn`. So you are not obliged even to show `Span` in the grid.